# retrieving values of the output parameters of a stored procedure

Tags: c#-4.0, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a stored procedure that returns an output.  The output parameters definition in the stored procedure is as follows:

```
@Success int output
```

I am using following statement to retrieve the values from the output parameters. I am getting the error message

> "Specified cast is not valid"

I am using Visual Studio 2012.

```
int returnVal = (int)myCOmmand.Parameters["@Success"].Value;
```

Can you please let me know what could be the problem? And provide the resolution.

Thanks for the assistance.
Yagya

Answer (score 1):

I created a parameter to get the value from after executing, like this (o_id is the parameter name):

```
IDbDataParameter o_id = cmd.CreateParameter();
o_id.ParameterName = "?o_id";
o_id.DbType = DbType.Int32;
o_id.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
cmd.Parameters.Add(o_id);

// Call the Stored Procedure
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.CommandText "= MyStoredProcedure";

db.ExecuteNonQuery(cmd);
int o_idValue =  int.Parse(o_id.Value.ToString());
```

In this case, `db` is a database layer, which executes my IDbCommand

Problably you can solve your issue with the `int.Parse()` (or even better, `int.TryParse()`)